# reason of using single quotes in json object

Tags: javascript, json

I'm studying differences between javascript object and json object, i know that 
in JSON we MUST always use double quotes on key names, i want to know why here 
is single quotes:

```js
var myJSON = '{"name":"John", "age":31, "city":"New York"}';
```

i know all other differences but don't know why we need that single quote which is used in many questions and examples but not explained.

Comment: This is s string you can use `JSON.parse(myJSON)` to convert it to `json`

Comment: Because the double quotes are part of the string.  If you tried delimiting the string with double quotes as well, you’d get an error.  So single quotes are used.

Comment: If you take away those single quotes, you will have yourself a Javascript object.  ps. @brk you obviously meant to say Javascript object too :)

Comment: And now it has double quotes surrounding it: `var myJSON = "{\"name\":\"John\", \"age\":31, \"city\":\"New York\"}";`

Comment: @James should this be obvious that not needed to explain ? why here its not used var data = {"firstName": "JAVA","lastName":"Kotlin","hobbies":"Writing"}. it is used here https://medium.com/techtrument/javascript-object-vs-json-117965ea3dea

Comment: If you have the single quotes, you just have a string, that later you can de-serialize into a Javascript Object,.. Without the quotes, you have yourself a Javascript Object, no parsing now needed.  That's the difference.  IOW  `'{"x":1}'` is not the same things as `{"x":1}`.

Comment: There is some questionable info on that page @joonas.  The part beginning with *Unlike JavaScript Object, a JSON Object has to be fed into a variable as a String and then parsed into JavaScript.* shows an example that would produce an error.